# Writing a SQL insert statement to add record to a database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My INSERT statement is as follows;

```
INSERT INTO StudentRecord ( Name, schoolid, age)
VALUES ('Hello', 1, '12')
```

I have 2 tables in my Database;

1st --

`School` and it has the following fields;

```
id, schoolName
```

2nd --

`StudentRecord`  and it has the following fileds;

```
studentid, studentName, schoolid, age
```

Now what i want to do is to add the Schools Name instead of schoolId into the insert statement, and save it in the `StudentRecord` table. How can i do this ?

For example the place where i have added `1` as schoolId should be the name of the school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the OP....there's some database theory you are a little foggy on and you need to understand it clearly before the answers people are giving you will make complete sense.

Don't look at raw data tables after an insert and expect every field to be a text representation of data.  You want to look at your data after its been inserted, using a query to join to the appropriate tables with one another to present the data in a readable format.  You don't insert it in a readable format.  You insert, then query and view it in a readable format.

You are denormalizing your database by using the school name in place of the ID.  Normalization is a critical concept in keeping redundancy out of your system and your db performance optimal.  E.g. Change in one place, one time, changes all records that use it. Understanding normalization will lead you to understanding why this is a bad solution.

Here's a couple of links for you.

[Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878)

[Wikipedia Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `insert ... select` instead of `insert ... values`:

```
insert  StudentRecord
        (Name, Schoolid, Age)
select  @StudentName
,       id
,       @StudentAge
from    Schools
where   schoolName = @SchoolName
```

I've added variables (like `@SchoolName`) where you would enter the values.

Comment: @ SchoolName means i have to give it some value, Right ? But, all what i am sending to the DB side is the `SCHOOLID`, so i will have to look up for SCHOOLID and find the corresponding SCHOOLNAME and save it. For this i will have to alter the StudentRecord Table.

Comment: That would store a lot of duplicate school names.  You'd better keep `schoolid` in the `StudentRecord` table.  You can always query the students with their school name with `select * from StudentRecord sr join School s on s.id = sr.schoolid`

Comment: In studentRecord, there 1 student may go to 1 school. Instead of saving the ID, i need to replace it with the school Name.

Answer (score 0):

Change schoolid to schoolName.

Retrieve the schoolName using the schoolid. (using SELECT)

Once retrieved, you can now store your schoolName there.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to modify your table..

ALTER TABLE StudentRecord
ALTER COLUMN schoolid varchar(100)

now simply enter school name in place of school id!

Comment: Ok, Table will be altered. But i am sending school ID, so i need to do something with the SQL so that it will look up for school ID and store the corresponding School Name

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why would you want to do this because you are de-normalizing the structure. You should also not be storing `age` because it changes and is a calculated field. Store the birth date instead.

But something like this may work:

```
INSERT INTO someTable
SELECT a.studentId, a.studentName, b.schoolName, a.age
FROM StudentRecord a
INNER JOIN School b ON b.id = a.schoolid
```

Comment: The OP is not asking to copy (all) rows, as your query would do.  He's asking how to insert by school name instead of school id.